# Why are the coefficients always equal?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Take the equation $ax^{2} + bx + c = 3x^{2} + 4x + 53$.

Why is it always true that $a = 3, b = 4$ and $c = 53$?

I've seen many examples like this where the coefficients are equated, and was just wondering why that is always true.

Comment: What do you mean by $ax^2+bx+c=3x^2+4x+53$?

Comment: That was just arbitrary. I meant why does a = d, b = e and d = f when $ax^{2}+bx+c = dx^{2} + ex = f$

Comment: If you have two elephants and 3 rhino does that equal 0 elephants and 1 rhino?

Comment: So we can take also $3=8$ if we are in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: @Chinny84 - Good point, but can you explain that to me a little more in depth?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel - What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you need to say are you talking over a field? can we use the  fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: The first respondent seems to have used the FTA. My question was more of a conceptual one, though, so use whatever you need to. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not over a field, you should use the fact that $1,x,x^2...$ are linearly independent.

Comment: The question as posed is missing the very important words "for all $x$." Without them, you _do not know_ that all coefficients are equal. You could very well have $a=4\neq 3$, $b=4$, $c=52\neq 53$, provided that $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Or to put it another way, if $a\neq 3$ then you have a quadratic equation to solve for $x$ rather than a formula that is true for all $x$; and if $a=3$ but $b\neq 4$ you have a linear equation with a unique solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that $ax^{2} + bx + c = 3x^{2} + 4x + 53$ for all $x$, or $ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53) = 0$ for all $x$.

$ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53) = 0$ is a polynomial with at most degree $2$ so by the fundamental theorem of algebra it has at most $2$ roots if it is not the zero polynomial.

But $ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53) = 0$ has infintely many roots (it is zero for every value of $x$), so it must be the zero polynomial. Then we have $a=3$, $b=4$ and $c=53$.

$$ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53) = (a-3)x^2+(b-4)x+(c-53)$$

Every coefficient must be equal to zero for it to be the zero polynomial, thus $a-3=0$, and $a=3$. Similiarly, one has $b=4$ and $c=53$.

Comment: Why does it have infinitely many roots?

Comment: Because it is zero everywhere. $ax^{2} + bx + c - 3x^{2} + 4x + 53 = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Not that it changes things much, but haven't you made a sign mistake in Line 2?

Comment: @SR1 I forgot to put brackets.

Comment: Why is that true? Sorry for the persistent questions.

Comment: How can you prove there are infinitely many roots?

Comment: $ax^{2} + bx + c = 3x^{2} + 4x + 53$, thus  $ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53)= (3x^{2} + 4x + 53) - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53)$, thus $ax^{2} + bx + c - (3x^{2} + 4x + 53)=0$. This holds for all $x$. Thus there are infinitely many roots. Note that $a$ is a root of $P(x)$ if $P(a)=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the kind of explanation I needed. But why is a = 3?

Comment: I think that the fact that the zero polynomial always has zero coefficient, is equivalent in every regard to the original question. In this context, this must be proven.

Answer (score 7):

The equation is valid for all $x$ take $x=0$ to get $c=53$. The equation now rewrites as follows $ax^2+bx=3x^2+4x$ and again this is true for all $x$ especially for say $x=-{4\over 3}$ and the equation now looks like ${16a\over 9}-{4b\over 3}=0$ and for $x=1$ we get $a+b=7$ the solution of the system in $(a,b)$ is $(3,4)$

In general if two polynomial are such as $a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0=b_nx^n+\cdots+b_0$ **for all x** this means $(a_n-b_n)x^n+\cdots+(a_0-b_0)$ has an infinity of solutions while it has degree $n$ and therefore all its coefficients are $0$ which translates into $a_i=b_i\,\forall i$

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted. But why does the last equation have an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: True. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a cute way of proving it I don't think has been mentioned yet.

If you agree two polynomials are equal, you should also agree that their *derivatives* are equal.

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = 3x^2+4x+53$.

Taking the derivative of $f$, we get:

$f'(x) = 2ax + b = 6x + 4$.

Taking the *second* derivative, we get:

$f''(x) = 2a = 6$.

Working backwards, we can solve for each variable in turn. The last equation gives $a = 3$. Going to the one before it, we can replace $2ax$ with $6x$ and subtract $6x$ from both sides to get $b=4$. And finally, we go back to the original to subtract $3x^2 + 4x$ from both sides to get $c=53$.

It's not the most efficient way, but it doesn't require any evaluation of the polynomial or talk of its roots.

Comment: You can use mathematical induction for a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ is a linear independent set in the vector space of real valued polynomials ($+$ and $\cdot$ defined in the obvious way). Then, by definition of linear independence,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i = \sum_{j=0}^m b_jx^j \iff a_i = b_j \quad \forall i,j<n=m.
$$

Comment: how does one prove that this set is independent. If referring to polynomials, rather than polynomial functions, this does not relate to the OP. If polynomial functions, you need to show what they want to show

Comment: @Shuri2060 yeah good point; this was a long time ago. In any case DanJenks answer is the proof of linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

To try and give a more general answer to why $a=d$, $b=e$ and $c=f$ given that $ax^{2} + bx + c = dx^{2} + ex + f$.

Rearranging gives $ax^{2} + bx + c - (dx^{2} + ex + f) = 0$, combining factors of $x$ gives $(a-d)x^{2} + (b-e)x + (c-f) = 0$.

It then follows that each of $(a-d)x^{2}$, $(b-e)x$ and $(c-f)$ must equal $0$.

If $x$ can have any value then $a - d = 0$ therefore $a = d$ with the same for $b = e$ and $c = f$.

It should be noted that values can be found that mean $a$ and $d$, $b$ and $e$, and $c$ and $f$ are not equal for specific values of $x$. Such as $x$ = $0$, which allows $a$, $b$, $d$ and $e$ to have any value.